# How to print the time zone of UTC and Europe and America in Dart?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, timestamp, datetime-format

I'm trying to print a `current time-stamp` in Dart, I need finally to print the `current time` in the following timezones:

- Europe
- American
- UTC

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show your progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method:

```dart
DateTime timeIn([Duration duration = Duration.zero]) {
  return DateTime.now().toUtc().add(duration);
}
```

Usage:

```dart
timeIn(); // UTC or GMT
timeIn(Duration(hours: 5, minutes: 30)); // +5.30 (IST)
timeIn(Duration(hours: 2)); // +2.00 (CEST)
timeIn(Duration(hours: -4)); // -4.00 (EDT)
timeIn(Duration(hours: -5)); // -5.00 (EST)
timeIn(Duration(hours: -7)); // -7.00 (MST)
timeIn(Duration(hours: -8)); // -8.00 (PST)
```